# Paperclip not saving the s3 file path in application db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am trying to upload the file s3 by paperclip & aws-sdk. The file is being saved to the s3 successfully but the application record is always contains nil value.

**Attachment Model:**

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_attached_file :attachment,
                    storage: :s3,
                    bucket: "test",
                    s3_credentials: "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    path: "test/:id/:style.:extension"
end
```

**Attachments Controller:**

```
class AttachmentsControllers < ApplicationController

  def create
   Attachment.create(attachment: params[:attachment])
  end

end
```

**Log:**

```
SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "attachments" ("attacheable_id", "attacheable_type", "attachment", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["attacheable_id", nil], ["attacheable_type", nil], ["attachment", nil], ["created_at", Mon, 04 Mar 2013 20:17:47 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Mon, 04 Mar 2013 20:17:47 UTC +00:00]]

[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving :test/11/original.jpg
[AWS S3 200 1.783004 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"test",:content_length=>21377,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>#<Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter:0xb5b91f80 @target=#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb2812290 @original_filename="544494_328200280615189_1305908665_n.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"song[attachment]\"; filename=\"544494_328200280615189_1305908665_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130305-9168-1brnfyd>>, @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/544494_328200280615189_1305908665_n20130305-9168-1r0pwtu.jpg>>,:key=>":test/11/original.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't make sense:

```
Attachment.create(attachment: [:attachment])
```

What your doing is passing in a hash to the create method. The hash has a key `attachment` which points at a value which is an array containing only the symbol `:attachment`.

You probably want to get the attachment from the params sent in to the controller action. Something like this:

```
Attachment.create(attachment: params[:attachment])
```

Also note that you should follow Rails' naming convention - a controller for the model Attachment should be named AttachmentsController

Comment: Can you post the content of `params`?